# Image clipTo Path with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, path, fabricjs

I'm trying to clip an image with a path but can't seem to find any help to do this with.

I've found examples to clip an image with a rectangle or circle, but a path example seems to be missing. I've also managed to clip the entire canvas with the path, but what I want is just clipping 1 image. Any help will be appreciated!

The following example is for clipping a canvas with the path.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setDimensions({width:_winWidth,height:_winHeight});

    var path = new fabric.Path('M2.9,245h-5.8c-35.3,0-69.3-14.4-93.3-39.4c-23.3-24.3-35.2-56.4-33.7-90.4c1.8-40.1,21-68.9,39.6-91.8l2.2-2.8\
    c10.6-13,22.6-27.8,23.6-43.4c0.9-14.6-7.1-27.8-15-38.9c-14.5-20.3-31-43.3-31-74.5c-0.1-28,11.5-55.1,32.4-76.1\
    C-57.2-233.1-29.8-245-2.9-245h5.8c27,0,54.3,11.9,75.1,32.7c21,21,32.5,48,32.4,76C110.4-105,93.9-82,79.4-61.7\
    c-7.9,11.1-15.9,24.4-15,38.9c1,15.6,13,30.4,23.6,43.4l2.2,2.8c18.6,22.9,37.8,51.7,39.6,91.8c1.5,34-10.4,66.2-33.7,90.4\
    C72.2,230.6,38.2,245,2.9,245z');

    path.centeredScaling = true;
    path.scale(1);

    //path.selectable = true;
    path.originX = 'center';
    path.originY = 'center';
    path.set({ left: (_winWidth/2), top: (_winHeight/2)});


    fabric.Image.fromURL('../images/home/2.jpg', function(img) {
        img.selectable = false;
        img.scale(1.2);
        canvas.centerObject(img);
        canvas.add(img);
        canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
            path.render(ctx);
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric', { selection: false });
var path = new fabric.Path('M 272.70141,238.71731 \
    C 206.46141,238.71731 152.70146,292.4773 152.70146,358.71731  \
    C 152.70146,493.47282 288.63461,528.80461 381.26391,662.02535 \
    C 468.83815,529.62199 609.82641,489.17075 609.82641,358.71731 \
    C 609.82641,292.47731 556.06651,238.7173 489.82641,238.71731  \
    C 441.77851,238.71731 400.42481,267.08774 381.26391,307.90481 \
    C 362.10311,267.08773 320.74941,238.7173 272.70141,238.71731  \
    z ');    
var scale = 100 / path.width;
path.set({ left: 20, top: 0, scaleX: scale, scaleY: scale,  fill: 'red', });
canvas.add(path);
addPattern(path);
canvas.renderAll();

function addPattern(obj){
  fabric.util.loadImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {

                obj.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
                    source: img,
                    repeat: 'no-repeat'
                }); 
                canvas.renderAll();
    });
}
```

Comment: Its Tested.Working Perfectly as Edwin Toh Asked.

Comment: You should add some explanations, what was the mistake, and what you correct in your code

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

To clip a single image, try this:-

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(img) {
    img.scale(0.5).set({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      angle: -15,
      clipTo: function (ctx) {
          path.render(ctx);
      }
    });
    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
  });
```

Note: I'd use `var myPath = xxxx` instead since 'path' is too close to SVG's `path`

Comment: This is the correct answer. I suggest to use path._render(ctx) and not path.render() to avoid problems with stroke, fill and path's own clipTo function.